# JavaScript function is not working. How to fix it?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I have the following JavaScript code:
[Link](http://www.nomorepasting.com/getpaste.php?pasteid=22561)

In which the function makewindows does not seem to be working.

It does actual create a window, however the html either contains what is quotes, or if I change it to

```
child1.document.write(json_encode($row2["ARTICLE_DESC"]));
```

to create a blank html page.

I moved this function to my main JavaScript file to include because I was getting errors before, but now no HTML is presented in the popupwindow. Is this because I am not retrieving article_Desc in thest3.php?

The other 2 files used are here:
[link](http://www.nomorepasting.com/getpaste.php?pasteid=22562)
and [test3.php](http://www.nomorepasting.com/getpaste.php?pasteid=22563)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> $row2["ARTICLE_DESC"] is PHP variable.

It is indeed a php variable, but **it is not being rendered as php because it is not enclosed in `<?php ?>` tags**

So, the correct way to do it is:

```
child1.document.write(<?php echo json_encode($row2["ARTICLE_DESC"]); ?>);
```

That way, the php, being a server side language, will render the value in $row2 before the page is rendered, so when the page finally gets rendered, that value will be in the javascript `write` function...as it's supposed to be.

Comment: That gives an error without telling what the error is..missing quotes?

Comment: json_encode is a php function, so it needs to be within the php tags

Comment: Would it be more logical to allow the function to take a parameter, or to use the above method. What would be the respective advantages/disadvantages?

Answer (score 2):

to print php variable you need php tags:

```
child1.document.write(<?php echo json_encode($row2["ARTICLE_DESC"]); ?>);
```

Comment: u need quotes here: document.write('<?php ?>');

Answer (score 0):

$row2["ARTICLE_DESC"] is PHP variable.

Answer (score -1):

I suspect that it is including the javascript after it has been parsed by the PHP interpreter.  Try adding a parameter to makewindows and pass the value you intend to use in via the parameter when you construct the HTML.

```
 ...
 <p><a href='#' onclick='makewindows('"
  . json_encode($row2["ARTICLE_DESC"])
  . "'); return false;'>...


function makewindows(html){
   child1 = window.open ("about:blank");
   child1.document.write(html);
   child1.document.close();
}
```

Comment: could you give an example? I tried passing $sql2 to makewindows but it did not like it.